AWS Cognito client credentials issue with AWS ALB
I have setup aws cognito user pools and multiple app clients under that pool. one of the app client(sales) only uses "OAuth grant types" = "Client credentials grant". When I try to integrate this app client(sales) with AWS ALB , I get below error.
InvalidLoadBalancerAction: The authorization code grant OAuth flow must be enabled in the user pool client
I only want client credentials type for M2M communication with my app running behind application load balancer.
Any idea how this can be fixed? or if you can provide any documentation for working with ALB and Cognito (M2M) would be helpful.
